# How to change the color of a dynamically created element?

Tags: jquery, html, pug

I have this dynamically created classroom which has 3 buttons on the side.

```
 for classroom in classrooms
   if classroom.author.id == user.id
      tr#bothcells
        td#classroomcell= classroom.classroomname
        td#buttonscell
           button.renameclassroom(data-toggle="tooltip", data-placement="top" ,title="Rename this classroom" type='button' style='font-size:15px', onclick='renameclassroom($(this))' value=classroom.id)
              i.fas.fa-pencil-alt
           button.showstudents(data-toggle="tooltip", data-placement="top" ,title="Show all students belonging to this classroom" style='font-size:15px' type='button',  onclick='get($(this))', value=classroom.id )
              i.fas.fa-user-graduate
           a.deleteclassroom(data-toggle="tooltip", data-placement="top" ,title="Delete this classroom" style='font-size:15px',href="/classroom/delete/" + classroom._id)
              i.fas.fa-times
```

..and this jQuery AJAX for getting the name of the students belonging to that classroom.

```
function get(a){
  var classroomvalue = a.val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/classroom/' + classroomvalue,
  })

  .done(function(data) {
    console.log('Get response:', JSON.stringify(data,  "", 2));
    $("#getResponse").html($(data).find('#students').html());
  })
  .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
    console.log('Ajax error response:', textStatus);
  });
};
```

Where do I struggle and what it's my question?
I need to change the button icon color when pressed since the classroom and the buttons are created dynamically, I know I can't use the Id but the value. I have a really hard time finding a solution, and I couldn't come up with anything.

UPDATED HTML GENERATED
[image]

Comment: Why does the title of your question mention a `div`? And what do you mean, *I know I can't use the Id but the value*? You mention changing the button*icon* color. Where is the icon set? An icon is usually a graghic, so to change it's color you may have to just change the icon.

Comment: Sorry, I need to change the div background, but I realized would be easier to explain how to change the color of the icon, since I can get a hint of doing that, I will be able to do the div as well.

Comment: The code you show has no `div`. Changing the background of a `div` is easy. Google search "jQuery change div background".

Comment: @lurker, I am not sure if you understood my question, I apologize if I didn't explain well enough. I need to change the color when pressed on, as :active in CSS. But they are dynamically created.

Comment: I probably haven't understood. I didn't see any code in your question that is dynamically creating any elements  Can't you dynamically create them with a unique Id (you can build the id in various ways) then create the click action function? You can also create an action on ids that match a pattern.

Comment: @AngelPolitis I have updated my post with generated HTML

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192081/discussion-between-alex-pop-and-lurker).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, having multiple elements share the same id is wrong, because the id attribute is meant to uniquely identify an element. That aside, you can get away with it in this case with the following code. You'd better use classes, however.

**Code:**

```js
function get (a) {
  var classroomvalue = a.val();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/classroom/' + classroomvalue,
  })
  .done(function (data) {
    console.log('Get response:', JSON.stringify(data, "", 2));
    $("#getResponse").html($(data).find('#students').html());

    /* Reset the colour of all buttons' icons. */
    a.closest("tbody").find("tr button > i").css("color", "");

    /* Make the current button's icon's colour red. */
    a.children("i").css("color", "red");
  });
};
```

Comment: The solution works, partially. If the icon is pressed, it goes red but just for a second. Turns back to the initial color. I believe this is the issue I have since all the buttons have the same id. That's why I need to get them by value not id, that's why I need jQuery not CSS. Or at least that's why I know.

Comment: The solution works if you keep the button down without releasing it. Isn't that what you want? Do you want it to change on click and remain changed?

Comment: By the way, you should really solve the issue with the duplicate and triplicate ids. Ids are meant to uniquely identify an HTML element. You should make them classes.

Comment: Sorry if I haven't explained myself well enough. The reason I am trying to do this, is for the user interface, to know which button for which classroom he has clicked. So the button needs to stay red, until the user refreshes or clicks on the same button but for the different classroom, where the button, again has to stay red.

Comment: What you want becomes very easy as long as you can change `td#buttonscell` to `td.buttonscell`.

Comment: I've done that, changed the ID to Class, same in CSS, now is not triggered at all.

Comment: Try the new code I've written. I've added the two commented lines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192082/discussion-between-alex-pop-and-angel-politis).